# PDFTextStripper : Begin at a specific string?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have extracted the text below from a PDF into a String using PDFTextStripper. What I want to be able to do now is to begin extracting text only at "1###(1)" and ignore all of the text before it. Any idea how I could do that?

`Official World Golf Ranking
Week 
Ending
Week###52   2013
Events###Points###Points###Events
This###Week###End###Name###Country###Average###Total###Played###Lost in###Gained in###Played
Week###49-2013###2012###Points###Points###(Divisor)###2013###2013###(Actual)
Min-40 Max-52
1###(1)###<3>###Tiger Woods###United States###11.6948###479.486###41###-350.080###488.254###41...`

Comment: text.substring(text.indexOf("1###(1)"))

Comment: Thank you very much! This saved me so much work. I went from about 40 lines of code to 1!